# Susu Linux delete directory older than 1 day

Tags: linux

Please help

I want to delete the directory and corresponding sub directories from a path and i tried the below command and for some reason it is not deleting .

Any help is appreciated .

```
/hana/export/PHO> ls -lrt
total 0
-rwxr-x---  1 phoadm sapsys  678 Sep  4 10:59 export_schema.sh
drwxr-x--- 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  5 00:23 2018-09-05
drwxr-x--- 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  6 00:23 2018-09-06
-rwxr-x---  1 phoadm sapsys  248 Sep  6 00:23 export_schema.out
phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO> find /hana/export/PHO/* -type d  -ctime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO> find /hana/export/PHO/* -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;

phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO>
```

It should delete 2018-09-05 directory but for some reason the above command not working .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
find /hana/export/PHO -type d  -ctime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

(without "*"), otherwise you are looking inside the directories not in PHO as you want, because "*" will be expanded by the shell.

Comment: phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO> ls -lrt
total 0
-rwxr-x---  1 phoadm sapsys  678 Sep  4 10:59 export_schema.sh
drwxrwxrwx 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  5 00:23 2018-09-05
drwxr-x--- 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  6 00:23 2018-09-06
drwxr-x--- 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  7 00:23 2018-09-07
-rwxr-x---  1 phoadm sapsys  248 Sep  7 00:23 export_schema.out
phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO> find /hana/export/PHO -type d  -ctime +1
phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO> find /hana/export/PHO -type d  -ctime +1 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
phoadm@SS4100:/hana/export/PHO>

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
find /hana/export/PHO/ -type d -mtime +1 -delete
```

Comment: Why?  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: No luck Andrei , please check log above , Thanks

Comment: No Luck Guys , Not working , please check the out log ..

Comment: phoadm@SS4100:/SS/export/PHO> ls -lrt
total 0
-rwxr-x---  1 phoadm sapsys  678 Sep  4 10:59 export_schema.sh
drwxrwxrwx 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  5 00:23 2018-09-05
drwxr-x--- 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  6 00:23 2018-09-06
drwxr-x--- 50 phoadm sapsys 4096 Sep  7 00:23 2018-09-07
-rwxr-x---  1 phoadm sapsys  248 Sep  7 00:23 export_schema.out
phoadm@SS4100:/SS/export/PHO> find /SS/export/PHO -type d  -ctime +1
phoadm@SS4100:/SS/export/PHO> find /SS/export/PHO -type d  -ctime +1 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
phoadm@SS4100:/SS/export/PHO>